# Drag and Drop TreeView to List Box in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, listbox, treeview

How to code Drag Treeview Parent or Root node and drop to List Box using asp.net please help me !

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Treeview control is not designed for the purpose that you want. In order to use drag & drop facility you have to use jQuery ([jstree](http://www.jstree.com/demo/)) plug-in or you may purchase [telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/draganddropnodes/defaultcs.aspx) controls if you can afford.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can see [this commercial Telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/applicationscenarios/treeviewdraganddrop/defaultcs.aspx) for drag & drop between RadTreeView and RadListBox.